# Passing single runnable object to multiple thread constructors

Tags: java, multithreading

If I create a runnable object

```
Runnable run = new MyRunnable();
```

And then pass the same exact object to two thread constructors and run them

```
new Thread(run).start;
new Thread(run).start;
```

1. Is the possible? What are the implications?
2. If I call Thread.sleep(0); in class MyRunnable, will both threads sleep because they are the same object, or is the thread entity completely separate from the object?
3. Would there ever be a reason to do this, if not please still answer the two questions above, because I don't think I fully understand the thread mechanism yet?

Comment: Why don't you test it out yourself and see?

Comment: Trying to discern what's going with thread, only through testing, can sometimes have inconclusive results because of the way threads are. I don't want to leave, in this case, the robustness of my program to chance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. It's definitely possible and legal. If your `Runnable` has no state (no fields), then everything will be fine. If your `Runnable` does have mutable state, then you may need to use one of Java's many *mutual exclusion mechanisms* like `ReentrantLock` or the `synchronized` keyword. Because both Threads will be mutating the fields of the same `Runnable` object.
2. No, you created and ran two different Threads. They simply call `Runnable.run()`.
3. It's not out of the realm of possibility. I wouldn't even say it's necessarily bad practice. Specific situations where you might do this left as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: 3. One usecase: Having a spring singleton component as a runnable.

Answer (score 11):

> 1. Is the possible? What are the implications?

Yes it is possible.

The implication is that any state in the Runnable is (potentially) shared by all threads, and access to / update of that state needs to be properly synchronized.

> 2. If I call Thread.sleep(0); in class MyRunnable, will both threads sleep because they are the same object, or is the thread entity completely separate from the object?

No, they won't.

The Thread is logically distinct from the `Runnable`.  Calling `Thread.sleep()` doesn't directly effect the `Runnable` and other threads that may be sharing it.  (It could effect other threads indirectly; e.g. if one thread sleeps while it is holding the Runnable's primitive lock, and the other threads need to acquire the lock to make progress.)

> 3. Would there ever be a reason to do this, if not please still answer the two questions above, because I don't think I fully understand the thread mechanism yet?

You *might* do this if there is no thread-specific state associated with the `Runnable` and you wanted to minimize space overheads, or the overheads of initializing the `Runnable` objects.  But use-cases where those overheads are significant are rare in practice.

In the vast majority of real-world use-cases, each thread needs a distinct `Runnable` instance anyway ... because you need to tell each thread to do something different to the others.