# Regarding same Runnable reference on Multiple Treads

Tags: java, multithreading

When we call `start()` on a Thread by passing a `Runnable` object as argument, can we pass the same `Runnable` reference to start multiple threads?

```
public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnableImpl impl = new MyRunnableImpl();
        new Thread(impl).start();
        new Thread(impl).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.*" This might throw `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849109/passing-single-runnable-object-to-multiple-thread-constructors

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I don't see how that's relevant. The OP is using the same Runnable for multiple threads, not starting the same thread multiple times.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. I've just noticed that. My bad. I didn't notice that he made an new instance of the Thread and called start on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this when your `Runnable` is implemented accordingly.

But you have to be careful your `Runnable` implementation does not contain a *mutable state*. You can control this in your own implementations, but the [`Runnable` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) does not specify.

```
// can be used for multiple Threads
class StatelessRunnable {
  public void run() {
    doSomething();
  }
}

// may go bang on the second execution -> use two instances
class StatefulRunnable {
  volatile boolean canRun = true;
  public void run() {
    if(!canRun) throw new IllegalStateException();
    canRun = false;
  }
}
```

In the above sample you see that you can use `StatelessRunnable` for as many threads as you like. In fact you could even make it a singleton. `StatefulRunnable` in contrast can be run *only once per instance*.

**Shared State**

Reading [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562520/17713) I realised there may be scenarios where you actually *want to share a state* of two `Runnable` instances. Of course a stateful `Runnable` instance is not always bound to fail with multiple threads, but this is much more trickier to get right than a stateless one.

```
// willingly share state over threads
class WillinglyStatefulRunnable {
  final BlockingQueue<Object> sharedObjects = new BlockingQueue<Object>();
  public void run() {
    sharedObjects.offer(new Object());
  }
}
```

The above example shows how you could work on a single collection `sharedObjects` with multiple threads.

**Literature Sidenote**:

Item 15 in [Joshau Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) says *Minimize Mutabilty*. This chapter - in case you have access to the book - addresses similar points in a much more general context. Shortly summarised he states that immutable objects make it easier to reuse instances and reduce the potential of illegal states.

Comment: i have just started reading java concurrency in practise, so expect few more questions in future..Thanks..

Comment: I know this is just example code to illustrate your answer, but, in the `StatefulRunnable`, shouldn't the `boolean canRun` be volatile, if it is going to be accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: Theoretically, `StatefulRunner` _may_ be able to be run more than once, since there is a race condition between checking `canRun` and setting it to `false`. If you want to ensure it can run only once, use an `AtomicBoolean`.